# Update old server

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have a file server I set up a few years ago. It is running ubuntu server 20.10. I haven't touched it in more than a year (other than connecting to the shared network folders). When I logged in today, it said this release is no longer supported, and that I need to do-release-update.

But when I do that, it says `the required dependency 'apt (>=2.1.10ubuntu0.3)' is not installed`

Currently:
`apt --version` yields `apt 2.1.10ubuntu0.2 (amd64)`

It doesn't currently have a keyboard or monitor hooked up, I do everything via ssh.  What needs to happen to get this caught back up?

Thanks!

I will try what is listed in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/6161) when I get home tonight, it has different instructions than https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/ which is what I'd been following...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 had one *fully QA-tested & supported* upgrade path; which was to the next release (being Ubuntu 21.04) but that door closed when [21.04 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/).  I know a number of bugs were filed by 20.10 users who missed the 21.04 chance & thus filed bug reports, and *Brian Murray* of the Ubuntu Release Team worked on issues to resolve that esp. for the future, but that was long ago. Ubuntu 20.10 was the first in the two year development cycle that concluded with release of 22.04 LTS

Comment: The next time you install a server, I'd advice you to install the latest LTS release (currently 22.04). This makes much more sense, and will allow you a 5 year window for upgrading.

Comment: @karel that might be what I'm looking for, I'll give that a try when I get home from work. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` wasn't in the instructions I was using,

Comment: FYI:  The upgrade instructions intended for Ubuntu 20.10 were https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HirsuteUpgrades  which mention `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core` rather clearly...